# Doctrine 2 - Outer join query

Tags: sql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In the context of the SonataAdminBundle / SonataUserBundle, I'm using the query builder to add static filters to the "list" query :

With this query, I get only users in the group "Juge", the query works well :

```
$query
  ->leftJoin( $query->getRootAlias().'.groups', 'g')
  ->andWhere( 'g.name = :group_name' )
  ->setParameter('group_name', 'Juge');
```

In an other Admin class, i want to do the oposite of this query : **get the users who ARE NOT in the "Juge" group**. How can I perform this? There is not outerJoin function in doctrine 2 right?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do

```
$query
  ->leftJoin( $query->getRootAlias().'.groups', 'g',
    Expr\Join::WITH, 'g.name = :group_name')
  ->where('g.name IS NULL')
  ->setParameter('group_name', 'Juge');
```

where `Expr` is `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr`.

Comment: This doesnt work for users who are in the Juge group and at least another group. Still looking for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code and it works for me, its a kind of Outer Join.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('u')
     ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
     ->leftJoin('u.group g WITH g.id = :groupId', false)
     ->where('g IS NULL')
     ->groupBy('u.id')
     ->setParameter('groupId', 12) 
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```