# Doctrine - How to get the records when primary key is NOT equal to foreign key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm learning Doctrine by making Symfony application and I have a problem with my code. 
I'm trying to get all records from `flashcards` table except for those that are placed inside `trash` table. In other words I need those flashcards which not exist in `trash` table.

`trash` and `flashcards` are related with one-to-one relation. The `flashcards's` primary key is the `trash's` foreign key so I tried something like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');
$expr = $qb->expr();

$query = $qb
    ->join('f.trash', 't')
    ->andWhere($expr->neq('t.flashcard', 'f.id'))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

The query is executed properly, there's no errors but also there's no returned records.

Could you write, please, why this ORM code doesn't return any records and could you give me some tips how to make it working?

Thanks in advance for every answer!

Comment: search SO for some other ideas. here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615215/write-not-in-in-doctrine-query-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an OUTER JOIN (which you will not find in the Doctrine but keep reading):

[image: OUTER JOIN]

Where
Table A = flashcards, Table B = trash;

Example Query to get that:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableB.id IS null
```

[more read on possible joins and their queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Using Doctrine does not force you to use its `queryBuilder`, you can use a plain SQL with Docktrine as well.

All what you need is to build query on your own and execute it with Doctrine connection as in [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#data-retrieval-and-manipulation):

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
```

There are no RIGHT JOINs, nor OUTER JOINs in Doctrine, my guess is that it is due to the nature of the project which is simplicity and more importantly a portability.

Perhaps this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588270/doctrine-2-outer-join-query) will also help you somehow if you want to give the query builder the last try.

Comment: O, thank you! Very clear answer and great explanation. I'm gonna learn about OUTER JOIN from your link. At now I created query based on question you linked and everything works properly.

Thank you again!